# Replace attachment in Outlook with zipped version possible?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

Is it possible to create a .Net application which can read my Outlook mailbox, and for each mail replace any attachment with its compressed replacement?

In short, the .NET application/addin should check my old mails one by one, if it has an attachment file, then zip it, and replace the original attachment file with the new zipped one.

This is to reduce the size consumed in my mailbox. is there any such tool already available online?

I am using .Net 2008/2012 and Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find exactly what I need, so started creating one. Here is the attempt - http://www.saurabhkumar.com/autozip/ It compresses(zips) mail attachments, just before the mail is sent. Saves the sender and recipient lots of headache.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are a few components available to work with outlook, popular ones: Redemption, Outlook Interop

To achieve what you said, should be fairly simple, retrieve the email and do whatever you like and save it.

Question off the topic: zip the attachments could reduce your mail size, but it will still be large sooner or later... why not think about other ways, for example, archive your emails and etc.?

Comment: Thought is that we have cloud storage, so almost 5 GB of mail box size. Having mail in the pst itself means i can instantly access mail fro many device etc. I would want to archive my mail only after there is no further possibility of efficiently storing the mail online.